# pd.to_datetime errors = 'ignore' strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called 'result' that contains a column called "Action". This column contains lots of strings, some of which are dates. I'm trying to convert the strings that contain dates into datetimes, ignoring the rows that don't contain dates because they will error out.

Normally I would use pd.to_datetime(column =, format =, errors = 'ignore') but in this case, that doesn't convert anything.

HOWEVER, when I change errors = 'coerce', it DOES convert the dates, but of course converts everything else to NaN. I want to use ignore because there is still valuable data in the other rows.

```
result["Action"] = pd.to_datetime(result["Action"], format = '%A %B %d %Y', errors = 'ignore')
```

[image: with ignore]

```
result["Action"] = pd.to_datetime(result["Action"], format = '%A %B %d %Y', errors = 'coerce')
```

[image: with coerce]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `errors` is set to `ignore`, then *[invalid parsing will return the input](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime)*. So in your case the input is `result["Action"]`(The entire column).

The solution to this problem is to apply `pd.to_datetime` rowwise with `errors='ignore'`. By doing so you will get the same row back if the row does not follow the `format`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Action': ['Tuesday November 30 2021', 'Appointment time clicked']})
>>> df
                     Action
0  Tuesday November 30 2021
1  Appointment time clicked
>>>
>>> def custom(action):
...     date_time = pd.to_datetime(action, format='%A %B %d %Y', errors='ignore')
...     return date_time
...
>>> df.Action = df.Action.apply(custom)
>>> df
                     Action
0       2021-11-30 00:00:00
1  Appointment time clicked
```

Comment: According to the documentation invalid parsing just refers to data that's not in the specified format:

If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.
If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input

That said, your solution works! It's strange that I would have to use .apply for ignored errors but not coerced ones.

Comment: this was a bug and is fixed in the upcoming pandas 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
tmp = pd.to_datetime(result["Action"], format='%A %B %d %Y', errors='coerce')
result.Action = result.Action.where(tmp.isna(), tmp.dt.date)
```

Result for

```
result = 
                      Action
0   Tuesday November 30 2021
1  Appointment time clicked:
2  Appointment date clicked:
3   Tuesday November 30 2021
4  Appointment time clicked:
5   Tuesday November 30 2021
6   Tuesday November 30 2021
```

is

```
                      Action
0                 2021-11-30
1  Appointment time clicked:
2  Appointment date clicked:
3                 2021-11-30
4  Appointment time clicked:
5                 2021-11-30
6                 2021-11-30
```

Answer (score 1):

One work around I can think of is to re-parse the DF if needed

```
for d in result['Action']:
  try:
    res = pd.to_datetime(d, format = '%A %B %d %Y')
    print(res)
  except:
    res = pd.to_datetime(d, format = '%A %B %d %Y', errors='ignore')
    print(res)
```